# What is the rationale behind git's decision of not commiting a new added file current contents but instead the contents of when it was added?

Tags: git, version-control

So, from what I've read in Pro Git,

> It turns out that Git stages a file
>   exactly as it is when you run the
>   `add` command. If you commit
>   now, the version of
>   `someFile` as it was
>   when you last ran the `add`
>   command is how it will go into the
>   commit, not the version of the file as
>   it looks in your working directory
>   when you run `commit`. If
>   you modify a file after you run
>   `add`, you have to run
>   `add` again to stage the
>   latest version of the file

it seems that when you add a file to your git repository, either you commit right away, or your if you make any modifications to that same file before the commit, those modifications won't be saved in that commit.

What is the rationale behind that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git doesn't track files, it tracks changes. So when you "add a file", you're not adding the *file*, you're adding the *changes* to that file, which in the case of a new file is all its content at the point that you added it. So, if you make changes after "adding the file" but before you commit, you have to add those new changes as well or they won't get committed.

Comment: Does that mean that generally I should only add files right before commiting?

Comment: You should do what works best for you. Personally, I only add the changes right before I commit (and often will commit a rapid-fire string of different changes if they make sense on their own), which includes any new files. YMMV, but it sounds like you'll be more comfortable (at least for now) if you get into the habit of only adding files immediately before you commit.

Comment: Its up to you. As Kromey said, it does not add files, it add changes. Also it gets added to the index stage first. This is the area, where the changes "stay", until they get committed. If you change an already file, you can just add it once more (remember: You add the new changes). Or you can also decide to make a second commit. I also add the files short before the commit, but I commit very often (Sometimes I "squash" them together later ;)).

Comment: This notion of adding changes is a little misleading. It really adds *snapshots*. It's still a snapshot from the time when you added it, so you can certainly think of it in terms of changes, but Git itself does ultimately think of them as snapshots.

Comment: @devoured: Adding right before committing is generally a good approach. One little tweak - if you're working on a change affecting many files, you might add individual files as you finish with them, or even just once you're done with one change, so that you can easily keep track of what's done and what's not.

Answer (score 2):

Almost always, it makes sense to commit immediately after an add, which is why `commit` has an `-a` option, and why practically every other VCS doesn't let you split the add and commit, even though they are separate stages internally.

There are some circumstances where it is very handy to do separately.  Some people use the staging area as a sort of temporary commit if they're not sure they want to keep the changes or not, and are still experimenting.  I prefer all my commits to be compilable, so I will sometimes do an `add` when I am ready to commit but have a bunch of compile errors.  That lets me do a `diff` on what I have changed while fixing compile errors in case I mess anything up.  It's also very handy if you want to split your changes into multiple commits for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very consistent with the way `git add` works for non-new files.

```
$ git checkout master # assume there is some file called code.c
# hack hack hack
$ git add code.c
# hack hack hack
$ git commit
```

This adds the file *as it looked at the time you did the git add*. In, say, svn, you wouldn't even do the add because `svn add` is only for new files. So it's one extra step (unless you use `git commit -a` as someone else said) but it gives you a lot more flexibility, to commit only some changes and leave others uncommitted, within the same file. Once you get comfortable with git, you may fall in love with the `git add -p` command for exactly this reason. :)